# Smooth sticky menu after scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/51/) .

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 110) {
            $('.menu-container').addClass( "fix-menu" );
              $(".slider").css("margin-top", "50px");

        } else {
            $('.menu-container').removeClass("fix-menu");
            $(".slider").css("margin-top", "0px");
          
        }

    });
```

menu get fix at the top by this code . but if you see the result carefully there's a jump after menu get fix .
then i added a `margin-top` to slider to have smooth and better action .
but still it's not smooth in acion .

Any advice ? Thanks

Comment: its super smooth on FF 40.0.2

Comment: did you see image jump when menu get fix?

Comment: okay, now its clear what you mean. When the menu changes to fixed, the entire page moves up to fill the gap in the top of the page where the menu was positioined

Comment: nice, yes that's what i mean :)

Comment: i wrote an answer on how to correct it below

Comment: make `position` of  `<ul>` `fixed` and just change its `height` `onScroll` with `transition` and add `margin`/`padding` to below content accordingly.

Comment: can you edit my fiddle please ? @vivek

Comment: @sani check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/k3AHM/52)

Comment: thanks but this effect is not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you set the top margin to 50px, when the menu is actually higher (closer to 110px). The difference is the jump of the image/content. If you move the content the same height as the menu is high, no jump occurs.

```
$(".slider").css("margin-top", "110px");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , did the trick . can i ask you something ? when menu change from fixed to  normal or relative , there is another jump . do you have any advice for that ?

Comment: well, your two menus look kind of different so theres a visual change, but no positional jumps. Try to match the margins, paddings and height closer

Comment: thanks zedd , this line of code help : else if(win.scrollTop() < 20) remove class